# Once I have the length of a string, how do I go about capturing the length number as an integer variable for use elsewhere?

Tags: c++, variables, capture, string-length

Below is my failed attempt, terminal reads 0 as the 'lengthCapture'. I have tried googling the answer with no joy.

My Text file is titled as 'Boogiedy.txt' and reads 'Boogiedy, Boogiedy, Boooooo'

The terminal reads:

```
Boogiedy, Boogiedy, Boooooo
27 
0
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string boogiedy;
    int lengthCapture = boogiedy.length();

    ifstream inputFile ("boogiedy.txt");

    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
            while (getline(inputFile,boogiedy))
            {
                cout <<boogiedy<< '\n';
                cout <<boogiedy.length() << endl;
            }
    }
    else
        cout << "file is not open" << '\n';

    inputFile.close();

    cout << lengthCapture << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are getting the size of the string your variable is still empty.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string boogiedy;
    int lengthCapture = 0;

    ifstream inputFile ("boogiedy.txt");

    if(inputFile.is_open())
    {
            while (getline(inputFile,boogiedy))
            {
                cout <<boogiedy<< '\n';
                cout <<boogiedy.length() << endl;
                lengthCapture += boogiedy.length();
            }
    }
    else
        cout << "file is not open" << '\n';

    inputFile.close();

    cout << lengthCapture << endl;
}
```